# How to save the state of the app with the current theme in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I'm doing the dark mode and light mode for my app but there is a problem with data persistence because when I restart the app my theme goes back to the default one and not to the one I left it to last time I was in the app, after some research I was proposed to use the shared_preferences plugin but I have no idea how to use it in my case because the way I'm changing the theme from dark to light is by changing the variable **ThemeMode themeMode** initial value in the **toggleDarkTheme()** and **toggleLightTheme()** methods as shown in the code below, so how do I save that value in my device using the shared_preferences?

My theme_provider.dart file:

```
// Flutter imports:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Package imports:
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final themeProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeProvider>((ref) {
  return ThemeProvider();
});

class ThemeProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeMode themeMode = ThemeMode.system;

  void toggleDarkTheme() {
    themeMode = ThemeMode.dark;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void toggleLightTheme() {
    themeMode = ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

mixin MyThemes {
  static final darkTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    ...
  );
  static final lightTheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    ...
  );
}
```

main.dart:

```
final themeStatus = watch(themeProvider);
    return MaterialApp(
      themeMode: themeStatus.themeMode,
      darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
      theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [theme_mode_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/theme_mode_handler) with [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) in my app for switching and persisting themes.

Here is an example:

Add `theme_mode_handler` to your `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  theme_mode_handler: ^3.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
```

Create a class that implements the `IThemeModeManager` interface:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:theme_mode_handler/theme_mode_manager_interface.dart';

class ThemeManager implements IThemeModeManager{
  @override
  Future<String> loadThemeMode() async {
    final _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return _prefs.getString("THEME_PREF");
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> saveThemeMode(String value) async {
    final _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return _prefs.setString("THEME_PREF", value);
  }
}
```

Wrap MaterialApp with `ThemeModeHandler` widget and pass it an instance of your manager:

```
import 'package:theme_mode_handler/theme_mode_handler.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ThemeModeHandler(
      manager: ThemeManager(),
      builder: (ThemeMode themeMode) {
        return MaterialApp(
          themeMode: themeMode,
          darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
          theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
          home: MyHomePage(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And then finally to change the theme you can use:

```
ThemeModeHandler.of(context).saveThemeMode(ThemeMode.dark); //Dark theme
ThemeModeHandler.of(context).saveThemeMode(ThemeMode.light); //Light theme
ThemeModeHandler.of(context).saveThemeMode(ThemeMode.system); //System theme
```

Comment: where should the 3rd part of the code should be going to? The ```ThemeModeHandler.of(context).saveThemeMode(ThemeMode.dark);```

Comment: @LakshanCosta You can use that code to change and persist the theme. Put it In your widget's onTap wherever you are showing a theme change option. It can be a dialog box or a drop-down button.

Answer (score 0):

See this boilerplate, there are dark and light themes.

I didn't use thme it but it works :
https://github.com/zubairehman/flutter-boilerplate-project

He use Mobx with Stores (see my_app.dart and themes_store.dart) and also Provider (my_app.dart).

All the color are set up in app_theme.dart

Comment: I checked the repo u linked, but it's a large one and I can't understand what is going on there, can you simplify the part which you used shared_preferences to save the data and also initialising that data on startup?